# Contact Form 7 checkbox with option to write text

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, drupal-contact-form

I need to make a form with the contact form 7 plugin, and for a list of checkboxes to be able to make the last option with others: , and if it is checked, to be able to enter text.. I can't really succeed.. do you have something suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional field Plugin for that.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

So for Checkbox "Other" You make the "Other Text" Field visible otherwise hidden.